# What is the Mac OS X equivalent of a Microsoft DOS batch file?

Tags: macos, automation

I am relatively new to the mac, and other than writing python scripts I can't figure out how to automate certain tasks like I would have in windows with a batch file.

Pointers and links to documentation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The traditional way of scripting Mac OS X is via [AppleScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleScript).  You can look through [Apple's developer documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/applescript/conceptual/applescriptx/AppleScriptX.html), and there are various tutorials around the Internet too:

- [Mac OS X Automation: AppleScript](http://macosxautomation.com/applescript/learn.html)
- [AppleScript for Absolute Beginners](http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:q53afkJZsK4J:files.macscripter.net/sourcebook/AS4ASb2.pdf+applescript+sourcebook&hl=en&gl=us&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESg32__50sxl0GuBeLvvDdS8lfDTW8Az13m44WGIo_4r3VNiwgDJzNTTbpJiWM2Rk_yFS_5fCgdGMOCv92-6n_df8jBgv1-I4Lzrf3qwRi4ZHLZGHcgMPZcIOr7tolO76vyTCwkc&sig=AHIEtbRvdO2A_U0USXvkDRJZokiGJfVg5A)
- [Applescript Tutorial 1](http://homepage.mac.com/swain/Macinchem/Applescript/AppScript_tut/AppScrip_tut_1/appscript_tut_1.htm)

A simpler option is to use [Automator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automator), which allows you to create workflows for data and programs, so it's like graphical batch file creation.  Some Automator tutorials:

- [Mac OS X Automation: Automator](http://macosxautomation.com/automator/learn.html)
- [Getting started with the Mac OS X Automator](http://mac.elated.com/2009/07/27/automator-tutorial-getting-started-with-the-mac-os-x-automator/)
- [Automator Basics](http://macapper.com/2007/05/28/tutorial-automator-basics/)

If you're doing something heavily Unixy, you also have access to the [Bourne shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell), [Perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl), and (as you already know) Python.  It'll be more difficult to manipulate other Mac programs this way, but you have all the text processing utilities you could ask for.

Comment: I am doing "unixy" stuff.  Of the three you mention (Bourne shell, Perl and Python), is any one a stand out "right" way or does it just depend on personal preference?

Comment: Whatever you're most familiar with is probably the best option. There's no reason not to use it if it works =)